# Android phone reboots while executing my own developed application

Tags: android, gps, screen-orientation

I developed an Android application that uses many services, including GPS and orientation (compass). The genre of the application is AR (augmented reality) and I'm moving image views around the screen in real-time depending on the phone orientation. However, after a while, the phone freezes for a second and then reboots (Motorola Droid). I'm unable to find any useful log about this event. The log in the Eclipse is cleared after the phone reboots; I use "adb logcat" command to write the log to a file on my PC. The last meaningful rows of information are:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1272): Displayed activity com.zlatko/.Main: 2656 ms (total 2656 ms)

D/CameraHal( 1050): Zoom callback param1: 65536, param2: 1

D/CameraHal( 1050): processZoom/1:0. stopped=1

D/CameraHal( 1050): Stored Zoom Data/0/1:0

D/dalvikvm( 1272): GC freed 8444 objects / 453552 bytes in 268ms

D/dalvikvm( 1656): GC freed 13158 objects / 456056 bytes in 257ms

D/dalvikvm( 1656): GC freed 23844 objects / 787840 bytes in 98ms

D/dalvikvm( 1656): GC freed 22942 objects / 756408 bytes in 94ms
```

How can I find the reason for this frustrating behavior? The logs don't offer insight, there are no explicit exceptions thrown, the system is indeterminate (that means, I cannot conclude at what point in time exactly the phone reboots)...

Any recommendation?

Comment: Are you logging things manually using the Log class? I'd be logging important class/function calls a lot to get more detailed behavior.

Comment: No, I don't log manually. That's a good thing to do, of course, but the weird thing is that no exception is thrown anywhere, the moment when the phone reboots is more or less, random. Maybe, one pattern I have discovered is that the phone reboots when I move my phone fast in several directions.

Comment: @Zlatko: For what is likely a Motorola-specific problem, you might consider posting your query (with more information, since I know they'll ask for it) over on the MOTODEV support forums.

Comment: Note there's a difference between a reboot (hardware resets) and a restart (android app framework dies and restarts).  Usually on a reboot you'll see an extra logo screen (e.g. Moto logo) before the boot animation.  If it's a reboot, there may be something in the kernel log.  If you can grab "adb bugreport" after the reboot and look for the *previous* kernel panic log you may find something.

Comment: @fadden Thanks for the provided shell command. Didn't know that it's for kernel log, although have seen it somewhere in the forums. Actually, my app is rebooting on the hardware level, since on beginning the Moto logo is showing up followed up by Android logo. Will take a look at the log.

Comment: Look for something like "LAST KMSG" and/or "LAST PANIC".  The device tries to save a snapshot of the "dmesg" log when it reboots.

Comment: @fadden I grabbed "adb bugreport" after the hardware reboot of the device, but was unable to find any useful pointer for the crash. At the following link, there is my bugreport paste (please, scroll down a bit to find the log): http://paste-it.net/public/hd23e5e/     I would be grateful if someone can help me decipher the bug report. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The bugreport you linked to has a possible answer in the "KERNEL PANIC CONSOLE LOG" section:

```
<1>[ 1845.425445] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
<1>[ 1845.425811] pgd = cdfd4000
<1>[ 1845.426025] [00000000] *pgd=8d16d031, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
<4>[ 1845.426879] Internal error: Oops: 817 [#1] PREEMPT
<4>[ 1845.427185] Modules linked in: tiwlan_drv sec modem_pm_driver netmux_linkdriver netmux
<4>[ 1845.428283] CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.29-omap1 #1)
<4>[ 1845.428497] PC is at SGXGetMiscInfoKM+0x310/0x348
<4>[ 1845.428680] LR is at List_PVRSRV_DEVICE_NODE_ForEach+0x1c/0x2c
```

Looks similar to [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7944) for a Milestone and a post from May 22 2010 on [this Motorola support forum](https://supportforums.motorola.com/thread/25936?start=450&tstart=0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. As I can conclude from the posts on the forum, there is no solution yet for this problem. Maybe in some future versions, these reboot problems will be overcomed.